# JavaScript: Stripping URLs in meta data without stripping whitespace in all strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate and pass valid JSON to store in a database. I'm also allowing a user to copy the meta-data. Unfortunately, the below is failing and I'd like to know how to strip just URLs to be valid, without removing whitespace from other key-value pairs.

Invalid example:

```
{ "hello" : "http : //google.com" }
```

Valid examples:

```
var metaDataContent = {"hello":"http://google.com"}    
var metaDataContent =  {"typeId":5,"mainEventId":301049,"meetingId":54,"title":"Hour of Power"}
```

I've already tried `metaDataContent.replace(RegExp(" ", "g"), "");` which will correctly strip the first example and store in the DB fine, but unfortunately, will also remove the spacing from `"title":"HourofPower"`

Any help with improving the regex would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if you tested the string to see if it was a URL before trimming the spaces?

Comment: metaDataContent is a string with a json format?

Comment: @iamryandrake I am confused, I think that metaDataContent should be a string, if not the replace methods will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of data contains `metaDataContent` but supposing that is a string with a JSON format you could cast this string to an object and then iterate through its properties. If the property value starts with the string '**http**' perform the replace:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(metaDataContent);
for (var p in obj) { 
  if (obj[p].indexOf('http') === 0){
    obj[p] = obj[p].replace(/ /g, "");
  }
}

metaDataContent = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know! Thank you